# Reducing a simple boundary value problem

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem

I'm currently working on a multi-step problem and got stuck. I've worked with ODEs before, but this time I was asked to multiply by $v(x)$, where $v(0) = 0$, and then reduce the problem to an integral.

I've recognized that I'm dealing with a boundary value problem, but I've never worked with those before and the papers I've read haven't been much help.

[image]

Comment: integrate the equation and use the integration by parts together with the bcs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrate the equation and use by parts for LHS of (2). The BC's allow the boundary term to vanish giving (3).